# Comprehensive List of Characteristics of Payoffs of Games

Tags: game-theory

Axelrod and Hamilton (1981) write that there are two characteristics to the payoff structure of the prisoner's dilemma:

- $T>R>P>S$ and
- $R>(S+T)/2$

Has someone published a comprehensive list of such characteristics for all possible games with Bernoulli payoffs?

EDIT: By Bernoulli payoffs I mean ordinal payoffs. By all possible games, I mean all possible 2x2 games.

EDIT: I was hoping to find a comprehensive list of inequalities and other constraints for all possible 2x2 games. The typology I'm looking for will give a set of constraints that define each game. For example $T>R>P>S$ and $R>(S+T)/2$ are the two constraints that define a PD game. Obviously each 2x2 game has at least one constraint, which is the order of preferences, but I would like to know which games have which other constraints.

Comment: Please clarify your question: a) what are Bernoulli payoffs?; b) by "possible" games do you mean all $2 \times 2$ games or all finite two-player games?

Comment: Bernoulli payoffs are ordinal payoffs. I meant all possible 2x2 games. Thanks for asking for clarification.

Comment: After your second edit: Be aware that the restriction $R > (S+T)/2$ is neither necessary nor usual for a Prisoner's Dilemma. It is a restriction assumed for the games in Axelrod's tournament.

Answer (score 1):

The first contribution for payoffs on an ordinal scale is Rapoport and Guyer (1966), "A taxonomy of $2 \times 2$ games", *General Systems* **11**, 203–214. This deals with the 78 strict (no ties allowed) ordinal $2 \times 2$ games. See also Rapoport, Guyer and Gordon (1976), *The $2 \times 2$ game*, University of Michigan Press.

A full taxonomy (including games with ties) is in Fraser and Kilgour (1986), "Non-strict ordinal $2 \times 2$ games: A comprehensive computer-assisted analysis of the 726 possibilities'', *Theory and Decision* **20**, 99–121.

An accessibile summary is [Kilgour and Fraser (1988)](//doi.org/10.1007/BF00132457).

A bit of reverse bibliographic search starting from these references should point you to discover other approaches.

Comment: I am awaiting copyright clearance from my library. Our current collection only goes back to 1999. Hopefully this article lays it out how I need. Thanks for the help

Comment: The two articles do not approach the typology or taxonomy of games in the way I mention. I founds Bruns (2015), which does something similar and is more recent, but it too does not report the preference ordering in a very accessible way.

Comment: Please clarify in your main question what kind of topology or taxonomy you are interested in.

Comment: I edited the original question. Thank you.